# Retrieve entity auto generated Id

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to find a way to retrieve the auto generated Id of an entity that is persisted in the database via cascade. I am using Hibernate 4.1.9, Spring data 1.2 and Spring framework 3.2.1. Here are the entities in question : Location, Home, Room.

Location parent class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Location implements Serializable
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "location_id", unique = true)
private long uuid;

// other attributes and methods not relevant
}
```

Home class extending a Location, referencing a set of Rooms

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "home")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "home_id")
public class Home extends Location implements Serializable
{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "containingHome", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Room> rooms;
// other attributes and methods not relevant
}
```

and finally the Room class referencing a Home object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "room_id")
public class Room extends Location implements Serializable
{

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "home_id")
protected Home containingHome;
// other attributes and methods not relevant
}
```

I am using Spring data to create Repositories for the entities.

LocationRepository

```
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Long>
{ }
```

The problem I am having is that I need the id in order to be able to retrieve the different objects from the database and that is generated automatically. The only way I can access the id through the element is if I get the managed object when I save it to the database. But if I try to save each location in turn like so:

```
Home home = new Home();
home = locationService.save(home) // service that just calls locationRepository.save method
Room bedroom = new Room(home);
bedroom = locationService.save(bedroom);
```

I get a duplicate entry of room in the database which I think is related to a Hibernate issue https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7404. If I just call

```
Home home = new Home();
Room bedroom = new Room(home);
locationService.save(home)
```

there are no doubles but I have no way to retrieve the room object since it was persisted on cascade and its id is 0. Is there a way to solve this without introducing other fields in the location like a unique name that I have to generate myself? Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**

If in the last case I have `home = locationService.save(home)` and then call `home.getUuid()` I get the right value which is normal I think since I retrieve a managed object. But if I do `bedroom.getUuid()` I get 0 since bedroom is not managed and so it has not had its id field updated with the value from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `home.getUuid();` (assuming you have a getter for that field) after the persist call?

You might be surprised, but Hibernate (and JPA) will update the in memory copy with the id.

Comment: I eddited my question, the problem is I don't know how to retrieve the room object id correctly.

Comment: So the real problem is that room isn't getting persisted when the enclosing home is, correct?

Comment: I can see the home and room entries in the tables in the database set up correctly if I make an SQL query but the bedroom object in the code is seen as an unsaved transient instance. So that means that the bedroom object is not added to the PersistenceContext when the home is? I am a bit confused if this is to be expected or not.

Comment: I think this is expected behavior when the objects are loosely coupled like this.  I am more of an OpenJPA guy, but there should be something like a `EntityManager.merge(bedroom)` call you can do to get the object managed and reloaded.

Comment: I actually did create a custom repository with a method to merge the location object, but calling it would introduce a new object in the database with a different id. I guess my only choice is to introduce a unique field that I set myself which kind of makes the auto generated id pointless. In any case, thank you for your help!